# How to iterate through a Stream of integers? and at the mean time during the iteration I have to check it for some conditions

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am writing a code for post, but I am facing some issues in the validations.

getDocumentIds is a list of integers and what I need is to iterate through the list and check whether that particular id is valid or not.

I have tried with the below code but, when i pass the list of values it is taking only the first value. It is not taking the values after the first one.

```
    Document document=               
    Optional.ofNullable(repositoryService.findById(Document.class,               
    memberNoteResource.getDocumentIds().stream()
    .iterator().next())).orElse(null);

    if (document == null) {
        throw new ApiException(ApiErrorCode.DEFAULT_400,
                "Save unsuccessful document id is not part of member note");
    }
```

The expected result is, I have to check for all the "getDocumentIds" passed and if some id is not present then i have to throw an error

Comment: Is not present where?

Comment: There's no sense in `Document document = Optional.ofNullable(longExpression).orElse(null);` The result is not different to just writing `Document document = longExpression;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `getDocumentIds` is a list of integers and what I need is *to iterate
>   through the list and check whether that particular id is valid or not.*

You could use `anyMatch` to validate if, for any of the `id`, there is no document present(assuming return value `null`).

```
if(memberNoteResource.getDocumentIds()
       .stream()
       .anyMatch((id)-> repositoryService.findById(Document.class,id) == null)) {
    throw new ApiException(ApiErrorCode.DEFAULT_400, 
             "Save unsuccessful document id is not part of member note");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you wanted is something like

```
    memberNoteResource.getDocumentIds().stream()
        .map((id)-> {
            repositoryService.findById(Document.class, id);
        }).map(Optional::ofNullable);
```

Then you can further chain it with .filter() to do some more check.